# FasterCSV Malformed Error

Tags: ruby, csv, openoffice.org, fastercsv

I am using fastercsv with no pain in my Rails application to parse users uploaded csv files.
But recently, one user has uploaded a csv file that throw FasterCSV::MalformedCSVError.

The weird part is that when I open his csv file by **openoffice** and **resave** it without any change. Surprise; the **resaved** csv is working without the malformed error.

I have checked the resaved file and differences between it and original file and found openoffice changed its contents in some cells.

**For example**,

Original having cell value: **"Mahmoud"**

But resaved having value  : **Mahmoud**   *without double quotes*

I can't find all differences because this file is more than 6000 lines

Any idea why this may happen? Or can I just resave the csv files by offenoffice lib (not manually) and then use fastercsv?

Comment: possibly an encoding issue. Try enforcing utf8 for example if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

CSV has many [specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) which may not be compatible. Running a headless OpenOffice to sanitize the data would be the safe solution.